# Android Google Maps onLocationChanged not called

Tags: android, google-maps

I know there are many threads about this problem but nothing gives me good answer. Function onLocationChanged seams to be never called.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Jesteś tutaj!"));
        }

        /* ... */
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 2, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 2, locationListener);
}
```

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure GPS is on in the device settings.